# Background Location service on Android

Tags: android, gps, location, android-service

I'm looking a way to get distance travelled by the user. On purpose I try services like this

```
public class GPSService extends Service {
private LocationListener listener;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private List<Location> locationList = new ArrayList<>();
private float distancetracking = 0;
private int j = 0;
private float finaldist = 0;
String provider;



public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){
    return null;
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            locationList.add(location);
            Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
            while (j < locationList.size() - 1) {
                Location loc1 = locationList.get(j);
                Location loc2 = locationList.get(j + 1);
                distancetracking += loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
                j++;
            }
            Log.d("service", String.valueOf(distancetracking));

            finaldist = distancetracking/1000;
            i.putExtra("coordinates", finaldist);
            sendBroadcast(i);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,0,0,listener);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }

    locationList.clear();
}
```

}
But when my app goes in background the location didn't receive any location...I was aware of some limitation but actually I didn't understand what to do. I'have to do that on purpose to calculta CO2 from the distance travelled

Comment: I recommend looking at this article. 
https://medium.com/robertohuertasm/building-an-android-service-that-never-stops-running-5868f304724b

This should help you I hope to make things more clear on background execution limit and getting location even when app is in background or kill state.

Comment: Did you have the same using java ?